# Prime printing. Ask for point out errors in the code

Tags: c

Put all the prime numbers of lim in the aa array. 
This function returns the number of the obtained prime numbers, and finally prints these prime numbers.

Here is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

int func(int lim,int aa[MAX])
{
  int i,count,num;
  num = 0;
  for(count = 2;count<lim;count++)
  {
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(count);i++)
    {
        if(count%i==0) 
          break;
    }
    if(i>sqrt(count))
        {
           aa[num]=i;
           num++;
        }   
  }
  return num;
}


int main()
{
  int limit,i,sum;
  int aa[MAX];
  printf("Please input an integer:");
  scanf("%d",&limit);
  sum=func(limit,aa);
  for(i=0;i<sum;i++)
  {
    if(i%10==0&&i!=0) 
       printf("\n");
    printf("%5d",aa[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, the results I got when I ran the program did not meet the expectations.

The error is that every run results have a *2* in the first place and loss the last number
e.g.
[image]
And it should be  2   3   5.

Comment: What is your expectations?

Comment: Put all the prime numbers of lim in the aa array.
This function returns the number of the obtained prime numbers, and finally prints these prime numbers.

Comment: `aa[num]=i;` should be `aa[num] = count;` I believe.

Comment: It is prints all prime numbers less than the number entered.

Comment: Remove `sqrt(count)` and have it outside the loop `sqrt(count)` is expensive and should be just done the once

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid floating point math for an integer problem**

Do not use `sqrt()`.

```
// for(i=2;i<=sqrt(count);i++)
for(i = 2; i <= count/i; i++)
```

**Do not iterate once `MAX` values found**

```
       aa[num]=i;
       num++;
       if (num == MAX) return num; //add
```

---

I'd recommend an `isprime()` helper function to simplify code.

```
int isprime(int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0)
    return num == 2;
  for (int divisor = 3; divisor <= num / divisor; divisor += 2) {
    if (num % divisor == 0)
      return 0;
  }
  return num > 1;
}

int func(int lim, int aa[MAX]) {
  size_t prime_index = 0;
  for(int prime_candidate = 2; prime_candidate <= lim; prime_candidate++) {
    if (isprime(prime_candidate)) {
      aa[num] = prime_candidate;
      num++;
      if (num == MAX) break;
    }   
  }
  return num;
}
```